# Xcode CustomDataViews : a debug info formatter for std::set?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, stl, pretty-print

**Xcode allows custom types debugging pretty-printing plug-ins** to be fed into /Developer/Library/Xcode/CustomDataViews.

Apparently Xcode does not natively see what's inside a std::set when debugging.

**What would be the formatter for std::set?** A simple .plist file with one entry appears to be sufficient for relatively simple types... what would it look like if it was sufficient?